# How to make an AnimatedContainer change height after intial widget build, instead of on Button Click

Tags: flutter, height, duration, animatedcontainer

```
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 3.0, right: 1),
                    child: AnimatedContainer(
                      duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                      height: voteCountList[0],
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: ColorChooser.graphColors[int.parse(optionsList[0]['color'])],
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(2))
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

As seen in my code snippet the height of the Animated Container is voteCountList[0], this works fine if the value is updated. However when the widget is initially build there is no animation and the height of the container is instantly = voteCountList[0]. I would like to implement the AnimatedContainer such that the height of the container is seen to animate from 0 to voteCountList[0]. This height needs to animated on build.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to use an AnimatedBuilder or create your own Animation controller one way to do it with the Animatedcontainer would be

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  Future<double> get _height => Future<double>.value(200);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 3.0, right: 1),
        child: FutureBuilder<double>(
          future: _height,
          initialData: 0.0,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            return AnimatedContainer(
              duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
              width: 200,
              height: snapshot.data, //voteCountList[0],
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.red,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(2))),
            );
        }
      )
    );
  }
}
```

You start a future with an initial value of 0.0 and after a tick the futures resolve (it's a value you already had, you only transformed it to a future to make him think it will be ready in a tick) and the animation will start from 0 to the resolved future voteCountList[0]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer, the problem is that my widget is stateless in nature and so I wasn't sure how to implement this solution. Is there any alternative you could offer

Comment: Well this solution works with StatelessWidget, check the update, with out an state there is no other idea I could offer

Comment: My bad, didn't understand the solution initially. It works great, thanks again for your help. I only had one issue, which I'll figure out, but I was doing the calculations for the container height in the widget build method. Where would you recommend calculating the height, since the future height needs to be assigned this value

Comment: you could do it in the Future<double> get _height method, do all the calculations there and at the end just return Future.value(the result of your calculation)

Comment: sorry, I'm new to dart and flutter and I'm having a bit of trouble with the height return function. I need to return a list of doubles, and need some space to do some calculations before it, could you show me how to write this height function.

Comment: The values I'm using in the calculations are received as variables in the constructor of the widget. Not sure how to access those variables in the method. I need to use the optionslist for the computation in the method.
`
class MiniGraph extends StatelessWidget {
  final double height;
  final double width;
  final List optionsList;
  final List voteCountList;
  final bool isColored;
  
  MiniGraph({this.height, this.width, this.optionsList, this.voteCountList, this.isColored});

  List<Future<double>> get _height {
    return [
      Future<double>.value(250)
    ];
  }
`

Comment: can you edit your post to see what calculations you do in the build method?

Comment: nvmd got it too work, thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: I added UniqueKey in futurebuilder so its triggered on each rebuild. Is this okay?

Comment: If thats what you want yeah, but there is a package now that may be useful for you https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_animate

Answer (score 1):

In initState update the value with timer. so Animation start after build.
I'm changing height of the container.

```
double heightValue=100.0;

void initState()
{
super.initState();
Timer(Duration(seconds: 0),(){
  setState(
(){
  heightValue=300.0;
});
});

}

AnimatedContainer(
      height: heightValue,
      width:200,
      color: Colors.red,
      child: Text('kk'),
      duration: Duration(seconds: 2)
  )
```

Comment: This method works well however my widget needs to be stateless and so will be difficult to implement the initState method. Do you have any other way I can fix this issue.